Show local file search by default in Outlook 365 attachment menu
In previous versions of Outlook, when I clicked the "attachment" icon, it would open a file browser to let me select the file I wanted to attach.
In Office 365, it shows me a long list of "recent" files (mostly on SharePoint or OneDrive), which rarely has the file I want (the files I attach are often auto-generated, and I haven't accessed them directly).
Every time, I have to go to the bottom of the list and click "Browse this PC" in order to open the file browser and select the file I want.
Is there a way to make the "Add attachment" button just directly open the file browser (best) or at least make the "Browse this PC" option more prominent in the menu, either by moving it to the top or by removing the list of recent files, which are rarely useful to me?
